# Custom Template Tag Queryset Not Returning Anything

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to implement a feature that displays the 5 most recently created events.  I decided to implement this with Django custom template tags (if this is not the best way, let me know).  What I have so far is:

In event_search.html (among other things):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load eventSearch_extras %}
<p>count: {{ recents.count }}</p>
<ul>
{% for e in recents %}
    <li> {{e.title}} </li>
{% empty %}
    <li> No recent events </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In eventSearch_extra.py:

```
from django import template
from eventSearch.models import Event

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('eventSearch/event_search.html')
def mostrecentevents():
    """Returns most 5 most recent events"""
    recents = Event.objects.order_by('-created_time')[:5]
    return {'recents': recents}
```

My issue here is that the queryset 'recents' appears to return empty to the template.  'count:' shows nothing & the for-loop defaults to 'No recent events'.

Comment: That looks like an extremely complicated way of doing things... are you just trying to show these "recents" on every page?

Comment: Nope, just the search page.  Whats the best way?

Comment: Just include them in the context data of the search pages view? I'm not sure if im missing something here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've loaded the [inclusion tag function,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) but not the individual tag, so the code to populate that information is never called; it's also laid out slightly oddly, so you're calling from the wrong place.

The main template calls the inclusion tag by using:

```
{% load eventSearch_extras %}
```

And you include the actual tag by calling

```
{{mostrecentevents}}
```

mostrecentevents goes off and runs the code, parses the html of event_search.html and puts it in the main template.  The way your code is set out just now, you'd be calling an inclusion tag from its own HTML.

Main template > `{% load inclusion_tags %} {{ actual_tag }}`

As an example, I have a restaurant template.  In that template is this code:

```
{% load restaurant_menu %}  <!--main inclusion tag .py file) --> 
{% menu %}  <!-- the actual tag code you want to run -->
```

in restaurant_menu.py I have the following (additional irrelevant stuff removed):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('core/_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def menu(context):
    filtered =  context['filtered']
    from core.models import MenuItem, FoodProfile, Ingredient, Recipe
    if filtered:
        restaurant = context['restaurant'].id
        filtered_menu = #stuff here 
        restaurant_menu = filtered_menu
    else:
        restaurant_menu = MenuItem.objects.filter(restaurant__pk=context['restaurant'].id)
    return {"restaurant_menu": restaurant_menu,
            "number_of_menu_items": restaurant_menu.count(),
            "filtered": filtered}
```

and the _menu.html page (underscored so I know it's a fragment) :

```
<ul>
    {% for item in course.list %}
        <li>
{{ item.number|floatformat:0 }}  {{ item.name }} {{ item.description }} {{ item.price  }} </li>
</li>{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

An [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.inclusion_tag) is used to render **another** template. It doesn't make sense to create an inclusion tag that renders `event_search.html`, then call that template tag inside `event_search.html` itself. Note that you haven't actually used the template tag (with `{% mostrecentevents %}`), all you have done is load the template tag library.

It would be easier to use a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) instead.

```
@register.simple_tag
def mostrecentevents():
    """Returns most 5 most recent events"""
    recents = Event.objects.order_by('-created_time')[:5]
    return recents
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{% load eventSearch_extras %}
{% mostrecentevents as recents %}
```

This loads the result of the template tag into the variable `recents`, and you can now do:

```
<p>count: {{ recents.count }}</p>
<ul>
{% for e in recents %}
    <li> {{e.title}} </li>
{% empty %}
    <li> No recent events </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note you can only use the `as recents` syntax with simple tags with Django 1.9+. For earlier versions, you can use an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) instead.

Comment: You're awesome! it saved my hours. But I didn't see this on django document, where did you see it? Thanks a lot..

Comment: @BurakÖztürk I’m not sure what you’re looking for links to... the answer already links to the Django docs several times.

Comment: I check this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag

Comment: That's the same page that I linked to (but for 1.9 instead of 1.11 because I wrote this answer a couple of years ago).